# ld: framework not found Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

After a pull I suddenly get the following error in xcode:

`ld: framework not found Crashlytics`

However my team mate has no problem. He updated Crashlytics and pushed his changes on SourceTree as it runs fine on his computer. Even if I totally remove the project and do a git clone, it still doens't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug in **SourceTree** that doesn't detect type changes in binary files. When your team mate updated Crashlytics and Fabric, source tree didn't recognise a few of the binary symlink changes it made. Solution is to do the following:

- Go to his terminal
- Navigate to his project folder  (`cd ~/folder/to/project`)
- Add the missing files (`git add --all`)
- Commit his changes from there (`git commit -a -m "My informational commit message"`)
- Push his changes (`git push origin branch_name`)
- And then finally on your computer do a pull (`git pull origin branch_name`)

Comment: I am using cocoapods. I tried deleting Pods directory and installing pods again. This did not make any effect. After reading your answer I acted slightly differently. I deleted the Pods directory, commited that, installed pods and commited again. Worked!

Comment: Imho, SourceTree (and other graphical tools) helps users build better commits by providing tools to easily extract related code changes, as opposed to "git add --all"-commiters making "Fixed stuff" commits.

Comment: Alternatively, use cocoapods to install and not commit the framework to repos.

Comment: Remember to tell him as well that this is a good reason to finally stop using SourceTree and be a real man by using the terminal instead :D 1+ for this line :D

Answer (score 21):

please add `$(inherited)` in `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build settings this worked for me.

Comment: I had that problem using React Native, it fixed it

Comment: This as well fixed for me for `React Native 0.56`

Comment: Fixes `react-native@0.59.9` as well.

Answer (score 16):

Check your TARGET - Build Settings - Other Linker Flags

If you just updated to `pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'` and there is `Crashlytics` exists, make it `FirebaseCrashlytics`.

And also check there is `Fabric`, If exists that remove it.
(Remove next line `framework` which is under Fabric line too)

It should build successfully now.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Check your TARGET - Build Settings - Other Linker Flags

If you just updated to pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' and there is Crashlytics exists, make it FirebaseCrashlytics.

Similarly if you will see in the terminal, pod which is removed please remove from
Other Linker Flags also
Example: Fabric, FirebaseInstanceID.
(Remove next line framework which is under Fabric, FirebaseInstanceID line too)

It should build successfully now.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have access to the original repo (in order to check in the missing files), re-adding the framework using Fabric´s helper-tool also works as a "repair" for the build.

Answer (score 1):

add $(inherited) in Framework Search Paths in Target Build Settings. Issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

- Just keep **Firebase/Crashlytics** and remove Crashlytics and Fabric from the pod file
- Use a **Physical** device

Answer (score -1):

Try 'pod install' before running

Answer (score -2):

> just find in Project .ld file  and  remove it From Project  and then
>   Debug,

*its working perfectly.*

after removing all your functionality stay as it is.
its not depended on that .ld file.

- so , solution for that one is to **remove** it.

Comment: try ones.  i have found this error in my code also. and its gone after remove that file from Project